# How to correctly migrate the code from angularjs to reactjs

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I'm trying to migrate the code from angular to react. Not sure if it's correct, just need some help if I'm going in the right direction or not. I don't know angular so I'm having confusion if the 'textdata' is something like a state in react and will I have to declare it in states at the top or not

The angular code

```
 $scope.textanalysis=function(){
  return $http.post('/api/analyse',{'snippetdesc': snippetDescription}).then(function(response){
      if(response.status==200){
          textdata=response.data
          textlen=snippetDescription.split(' ').length
      }else{
          console.log('danger','An error has occured while updating the snippet. Please try again');
      }
  })
}
```

The one which I translated to react

```
componentDidMount() {
textanalysis(){  
fetch('/api/analyse', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      snippetdesc: 'snippetDescription'
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  }).then(response => {
      return response.json()
    }).then(textdata => {
      this.setState({
        textdata = response.data
        textlen=snippetDescription.split(' ').length
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Hope it will work.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textdata: [],
      textlen: 0
    };
  }

textanalysis(){  
fetch('/api/analyse', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      snippetdesc: 'snippetDescription'
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    }
  })
  .then(response =>  response.json())
  .then((textdata) => {
      this.setState({
        textdata : textdata.data,
        textlen : snippetDescription.split(' ').length
      });
    },(error) => {
          console.log(error)
    })
}  
}
```

Comment: why is it textdata.data, shouldn't it be response.data?

Comment: textdata you have represented as response inside then, so whatever data comes in response will be present in textdata. In your code you have wrote response.data but you are mentioning textdata inside then, so it will become textdata.data.